# TFS Build Error : System.Diagnostics.Assert is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, selenium

I am trying to run selenium tests as part of build. I have a set-up build agent and test agent on same machine and but I am keep getting the following error

```
Z:\Builds\1\box\Tests\Sources\Test1\TestBrowser\SeleniumBrowser.vb (190): 'System.Diagnostics.Assert' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.
```

I have a class which is implementing ISelenium it is failing where ever I am asserting. e.g

```
If ControlFound <> True Then
        Assert.Fail("Expected : " & pControlId & "was not found")
End If
```

I am running the scripts successfully in teamcity. It is just failing in TFS.

Edited:
Just figured out I am using nunit for VS to make tests to run from TFS. So when the build is running from TFS it is not recognising the nunit framework which is making the assert. Any Idea how to solve this.

Comment: "Friend" would seem to imply that it should be accessible.  That doesn't make much sense at all.  Friend assembly == internals are accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error is accurate, Assert is an internal class in the System.Diagnostics namespace.  Assert.Fail(string) is a method of the Microsoft testing framework.  You'd need

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestingTools.UnitTesting
```

at the top of your program to make that compile.  However, you said you were using Selenium so that doesn't exactly sound like the right thing to do.  It has its own set of asserts, be sure to review the Selenium how-tos and manual.

Comment: Sorry to mention before, I already am importing nunit framework. Do I still need to add this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error in Visual Studio 2015. In VS2015 you have to add a reference to:

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework`

In the code window you have to add at the top:

`Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`

Comment: @johnny5 what do you mean with "now" ?